# if (true) { "@Ajax.BeginForm{" } .. if (true) { " } " } -- How break begin form

Tags: asp.net, ajax, forms, razor

I need to put in the start of `"BeginForm"` in first `"if(){}"` and end of "BeginForm" in second `"if(){}"`

like this

```
if (true) { @Html.Raw("<form>");  }  ..  if (true) {   @Html.Raw("</form>");  }
```

How this can be done using Ajax.BeginForm() ?

Answer (score 1):

try something like following:

```
if (true) { @Html.Raw("<form data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace">");  }  ..  if (true) {   @Html.Raw("</form>");  }
```